# How can I get values of response variable in other view in swift ...when I try to access this variable it returns nil...need to solve this

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I just want to get all the values of response variable in (Agent view controller class) when I try to get using object it returns nil I have tried in many ways but still getting nil....in agent view controller I'm assigning all those runtime values to uitextview

```
import UIKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    weak var delegateL:AgentprofileViewController!
    
  
    var user : [UserModel] = []
    
    let mm = Usersmanager()

    
    //MARK:-- Outlets
    
    @IBOutlet public weak var txtPhoneNumber: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet public weak var txtPassword: UITextField!
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
    }
    //Functions
   
    @IBAction func btnLogin(_ sender: Any) {
        
       
        //below is the response variable which I want in other (Agent view controller class)
        
        let response = mm.alluser(phoneNo: txtPhoneNumber.text!, Password: txtPassword.text!)
        
        
        
        if response.count ?? 0 > 0
        {

            //uncom
            

            delegateL.runtimeid? = response[0].u_id
            delegateL.runtimename? = response[0].u_name!
            delegateL.runtimephone? = response[0].phoneNumber!
            delegateL.runtimepassword? = response[0].password!
            delegateL.runtimeaddress? = response[0].address!
            delegateL.runtimerid? = response[0].r_id!
            delegateL.runtimername? = response[0].r_name!




            print(response[0].u_id)
            print(response[0].u_name)
            print(response[0].password)
            print(response[0].phoneNumber)
            print(response[0].address)
            print(response[0].r_id)
            print(response[0].r_name)
            
            
   
      if response[0].r_name=="Agent"
      {


        
        
        
                let next : tabViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabViewController") as! tabViewController
        
        
        
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(next, animated: true)
        
        

        
        
            showalertforloginsuccess()
            print("Login Successfull")
            
            
            //Passing view to the next view if login is succesfull
            
      //  let next : HomeViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController

        //    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(next, animated: true)
            
            
            }
      else{
        
        print("Login Succesfull but login person is not agent")
            }
           
        }
        else
        {
            showalertforloginfail()
            print("Not Login")
            
        }
        
    }
```

This one is Agent Controller class where I want to access response variable values

```
import UIKit

class AgentprofileViewController: UIViewController {
    
    

 
    @IBOutlet weak var txtid: UITextView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var txtname: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtphone: UITextView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var txtrid: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtpass: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtrname: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtaddress: UITextView!
    
    var runtimeid:Int? = 0
    var runtimename:String?=""
    var runtimepassword:String?=""
    var runtimeaddress:String?=""
    var runtimephone:String?=""
    var runtimerid:Int? = 0
    var runtimername:String?=""

    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
//below all runtime variables contain nil 

                    print(runtimeid)
                    print(runtimename)
                    print(runtimeaddress)
                    print(runtimepassword)
                    print(runtimephone)
                    print(runtimerid)
                    print(runtimername)
        
       result()
        
        
    }
  
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        
        self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.title = "Profile"
 
    }
    
    func result() {
        
        //uncom
        
   //below is the error(txtid...contain nill while wrapping)

        txtid.text = "\(String(describing: runtimeid))"

        txtname.text = runtimename

        txtpass.text = runtimepassword

        txtphone.text = runtimephone

        txtaddress.text = runtimeaddress

        txtrid.text = "\(String(describing: runtimerid))"

        txtrname.text = runtimername


    
    }
}
```

Comment: It's very difficult to help with the code you posted... what is `Usersmanager()`? what is `UserModel`? you show `weak var delegateL:AgentprofileViewController!` but you don't show where that is created? Start simple -- figure out how to manage ***ONE*** variable between classes. After you get that working, start implementing multiple variables and/or variable structures or objects.

Comment: bro UserManager is a class which contain functions  interacting with database through Api get data from there ...response variable contain all the data from the database but I'm unable to pass the data to another controller class .....thats what I want ....and delegateL is created in Loginview controller and using that object I'm trying to pass data to another viewcontroller but get nil in return

Comment: and UserModel is a class where all the variables are declared

Comment: In the code you posted, `delegateL` is ***NOT*** "created in Loginview controller" ... all you've done is **declare** it. That may be your problem. Again, though, I strongly suggest you work on a simple, single variable that you can access and update between view controllers to get an understanding of how that works.

Comment: can you please give me an example then I can follow that ?